# Exclude a portion of a string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the string below:

Identification of the product - **AZEC**

How can I create a regex to exclude **Identification of the product -**  and return only the string that comes next, in this case, **AZEC**

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java for this task

Comment: Then add the language tag.

Comment: I tried \-(.*) but it also returns the - and the space after it

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "Identification of the product - AZEC";
System.out.println(str.split(" - ")[1]); // AZEC
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the one below and this seems to work:

(?m)(?<=\bIdentification of the product - ).*$